# Has Python 3 to_bytes been back-ported to python 2.7?

Tags: python

This is the function I'm after: -

http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

I need big endianness support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your original question, the `to_bytes` method for `int` objects was not back ported to Python 2.7 from Python 3.  It was considered but ultimately rejected.  See the discussion [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue1023290).

Answer (score 17):

Based on the answer from @nneonneo, here is a function that emulates the to_bytes API:

```
def to_bytes(n, length, endianess='big'):
    h = '%x' % n
    s = ('0'*(len(h) % 2) + h).zfill(length*2).decode('hex')
    return s if endianess == 'big' else s[::-1]
```

Comment: Not really the _entire_ [API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Python 3: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode', so it's not a portable solution for 2/3 compatibility.

Comment: For Python 3.4, you need 'h = hex(n).encode('ascii')[2:]'

Comment: Instead of `len(h)` and `zfill`, you can use `s = '{:0{}x}'.format(n, length*2).decode('hex')`

Answer (score 8):

To pack arbitrary-length `long`s in Python 2.x, you can use the following:

```
>>> n = 123456789012345678901234567890L
>>> h = '%x' % n
>>> s = ('0'*(len(h) % 2) + h).decode('hex')
>>> s
'\x01\x8e\xe9\x0f\xf6\xc3s\xe0\xeeN?\n\xd2'
```

This outputs the number in big-endian order; for little endian, reverse the string (`s[::-1]`).

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) instead:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>i', 123)
'\x00\x00\x00{'
```

It doesn't do arbitrary lengths in the way `int.to_bytes` does, but I doubt you need that.

Comment: So use a wider datatype. If you need more than 64 bits, you'll need to do some work yourself first.