# Python 3.5 to_bytes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, steam, steambot

I am programming a steam bot. One library was written in Python 3.5 but i need it in Python 2.7 so I am re-writing it. But I don't know how to rewrite this function can somebody please help me?

```
def steam_id_to_account_id(steam_id):
  return unicode(struct.unpack(u'>L', int(steam_id).to_bytes(8, byteorder=u'big')[4:])[0])
```

steam_id is going to be an integer like 76561198081423873
and it should return account_id in case for 76561198081423873 it would be 121158145

Does somebody know how to deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has Python 3 to\_bytes been back-ported to python 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022556/has-python-3-to-bytes-been-back-ported-to-python-2-7)

Comment: why do you need it in python 2.7? wouldn't it be easier to just move (yourself) to python 3.5?

Comment: Well another (more complicated) library is for python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that is some AMAZINGLY overcomplicated code...

```
def steam_id_to_account_id(steam_id):
    return steam_id & 0xFFFFFFFF
```