# convert CRC value to bytes

Tags: python

I use python2.7 in windows. I want to calculate the crc value of an array of data to send it via serial port. The crc value calculated is 794(int). I have to convert it to bytes and attach it to the data to send.

I have tried:

```
import struct
struct.pack("<H", 794)
```

and `bytes(794)`

But the value got are 794.
How to convert int 794 to bytes in python 2.7?

Comment: What exactly do you want as an output? `struct.pack` converts the int to bytes.

Comment: Have you tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022556/has-python-3-to-bytes-been-back-ported-to-python-2-7

Answer (score 0):

This should help - where n is an integer

```
str(n).encode()
```